# Opengl depth buffer to cuda

Tags: opengl, cuda, depth-buffer, zbuffer

I'm a new programmer to Opengl,
my aim is to retrieve the depth buffer into a FBO to be able to transfer to cuda without using glReadpixels.

Here is what I've already done:

```
void make_Fbo()
{

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                               GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
                           GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                                           fbo);
    check_gl_error("make_fbo");
}


void make_render_buffer()
{
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rb);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rb);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                          GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
                               win.width,
                               win.height);
    check_gl_error("make render_buffer");
}
```

This code create my FBO with correct depth values.

A new problem appear now, according to the article "fast triangle rasterization using irregular z-buffer on cuda"
It's not possible to acces to depth buffer attached to the FBO from Cuda.

Here is is the quote from the article:

> Textures or render buffers can be attached onto the depth
>   attachment point of FBOs to accommodate the depth values. However, as far as
>   we have tested, they cannot be accessed by CUDA kernels. [...]
>   we managed to use the color attachment points on the FBO. Apparently
>   in this case we have to write a simple shader program to dump the depth values onto
>   the color channels of the frame buffer. According to the GLSL specification [KBR06],
>   the special variable gl_FragCoord

Are the statements still true?
What do you advise me to dump the depth buffer to the color channels?
to a texture ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes and no. The problem is that you can't access resources in CUDA while they are bound to the FBO.

As I understand it, with `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage()` you enable cuda access to any type of image data. So if you use a depth buffer that is a rendertarget and is NOT bound to the FBO, you can use it.

Here's the cuda API information:

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OPENGL.html#group__CUDART__OPENGL_1g80d12187ae7590807c7676697d9fe03d

And in this article they explain that you should round-robin or double-buffer the depth-buffer, or copy the data before using it in CUDA (but then you more or less void the whole idea of interop).

http://codekea.com/xLj7d1ya5gD6/modifying-opengl-fbo-texture-attachment-in-cuda.html